# how to stop / speed up signed jar verification

Tags: java, jar

I have a tiny app (in Eclipse) that reads an HTTPS URL. When I run it it sometimes takes forever. Breaking into it while it is thinking shows that it is sitting doing jar verification

```
ByteArrayAccess.b2iBig64(byte[], int, int[]) line: not available    
SHA2$SHA256(SHA2).implCompress(byte[], int) line: not available 
SHA2$SHA256(DigestBase).implCompressMultiBlock(byte[], int, int) line: not available    
SHA2$SHA256(DigestBase).engineUpdate(byte[], int, int) line: not available  
MessageDigest$Delegate.engineUpdate(byte[], int, int) line: not available   
MessageDigest$Delegate(MessageDigest).update(byte[], int, int) line: not available  
ManifestDigester.manifestDigest(MessageDigest) line: not available  
SignatureFileVerifier.verifyManifestHash(Manifest, ManifestDigester, List<Object>) line: not available  
SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(Hashtable<String,CodeSigner[]>, List<Object>) line: not available 
SignatureFileVerifier.process(Hashtable<String,CodeSigner[]>, List<Object>) line: not available 
JarVerifier.processEntry(ManifestEntryVerifier) line: not available 
JarVerifier.update(int, byte[], int, int, ManifestEntryVerifier) line: not available    
URLJarFile(JarFile).initializeVerifier() line: not available    
URLJarFile(JarFile).getInputStream(ZipEntry) line: not available    
JarVerifier.verifySingleJar(URL) line: 466  
JarVerifier.verifyJars(URL, List<String>) line: 361 
JarVerifier.verify() line: 289  
JceSecurity.verifyProviderJar(URL) line: 159
```

And Url = `/C:/Program%20Files/Java/jre1.8.0_144/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar`

Is there someway I can tell it to stop doing this. Its not always and I can't find what is making it start doing it, yesterday it was all the time, today it is once out of 20 runs.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark... I have seen conditional breakpoints (that get evaluated bazzillions of times) slow down code when run in eclipse; without the breakpoints our running outside of eclipse it runs fine.

Comment: i have no conditional breakpoints

Comment: Why are you using HTTPS to read a file on your own file system? And why are you reading a JAR file that is a component of the JRE?

Comment: @EJP - I am not doing any of that. The https stack is doing it all by itself. I am simply doing an HTTPS get to my own web server